# Can I bind value from <option> to object field as integer in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

I have such form on my jsp page:

```
<form:select class="form-control" path="mark" >
   <c:forEach begin="1" end="10" var="i" >
    <option value="${i}">${i}</option>
   </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

And I want to bind selected value to field in object:

```
@Entity
public class Feedback {
    private Integer mark;
    // getters, setters...
}
```

Now, I has exception TypeMismatch: Cannot conver "String" to "Integer".

How can I save to entity integer value from < select>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the **TypeMismatch Exception** because you are trying to bind a `String`(the request parameter has a String value) to an `Integer`.

You just need to parse its value to get an int, use `Integer.parseInt()` :

```
Feedback feedback = new Feedback();
if(request.getParameter("radios") != null) {
    feedback.setMark(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("radios")));
}
```

And add `name="radios"` to your `select`:

```
<form:select class="form-control" name="radios" path="mark" >
   <c:forEach begin="1" end="10" var="i" >
    <option value="${i}">${i}</option>
   </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

Answer (score 0):

All the request parameters are in String form hence, I would ask you to change the variable from Integer to String and then cast it to the Integer before the logic you want to process.

Answer (score 0):

This binding works perfectly for me. For more clean way you can use bean in-between to bind and then you can convert String to primitive before saving.